# Javascript slidedown hover LI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover

i am having a problem in a hover LI that he hover all the li´s and not the one i have hovering.

**html:**

```
<div id="lista">
      <ul>
        <li>
             <a href="#">content1</a>
           <div class="slide">hide content1</div>
        </li
       <li>
             <a href="#">content2</a>
           <div class="slide">hide content2</div>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
```

**javascript:**

```
$('#lista li ').hover(function () {
$('.slide').slideDown('slow');
}, function () {
$('.slide').slideUp('fast');
});
});
```

Comment: Well, `$('.slide')` will select every element with class `slide`. You should only select the one that is inside the hovered `li`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#lista li ').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).children('.slide').slideDown('slow');
    },
    function () {
       $(this).children('.slide').slideDown('slow');
    }
);
```

Explanation: Each time you hover a `#lista li` element, you have to refer to its children `.slide` element . If you just do $('.slide'), it means that you are referring to each `.slide` element in the whole document ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try `.mouseover` instead of `.hover`

Comment: also your syntax is run for the slide `$('.slide').slideDown('slow', function () { $('.slide').slideUp('fast'); });`

Comment: .slide is the name of the hidden div that will slidedown for every li.